# Jensen-Shannon divergence calculation for 3 prob distributions: Is this ok?

Tags: distance-functions, information-theory

I would like to calculate the jensen-shannon divergence for he following 3 distributions. Is the calculation below correct? (I followed [the JSD formula from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence)):

```
P1  a:1/2  b:1/2    c:0
P2  a:0    b:1/10   c:9/10
P3  a:1/3  b:1/3    c:1/3
All distributions have equal weights, ie 1/3.

JSD(P1, P2, P3) = H[(1/6, 1/6, 0) + (0, 1/30, 9/30) + (1/9,1/9,1/9)] - 
                 [1/3*H[(1/2,1/2,0)] + 1/3*H[(0,1/10,9/10)] + 1/3*H[(1/3,1/3,1/3)]]

JSD(P1, P2, P3) = H[(1/6, 1/5, 9/30)] - [0 + 1/3*0.693 + 0] = 1.098-0.693 = 0.867
```

Thanks in advance...

***EDIT*** Here's some simple dirty Python code that calculates this as well:

```
    def entropy(prob_dist, base=math.e):
        return -sum([p * math.log(p,base) for p in prob_dist if p != 0])

    def jsd(prob_dists, base=math.e):
        weight = 1/len(prob_dists) #all same weight
        js_left = [0,0,0]
        js_right = 0    
        for pd in prob_dists:
            js_left[0] += pd[0]*weight
            js_left[1] += pd[1]*weight
            js_left[2] += pd[2]*weight
            js_right += weight*entropy(pd,base)
        return entropy(js_left)-js_right

usage: jsd([[1/2,1/2,0],[0,1/10,9/10],[1/3,1/3,1/3]])
```

Comment: Nice Python code by the way!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is mistake in the mixture distribution. It should be $(5/18, 28/90, 37/90)$
 instead of $(1/6, 1/5, 9/30)$ which does not sum up to 1. The entropy (with natural log) of that is 1.084503. Your other entropy terms are wrong.

I will give the detail of one computation:

$$H(1/2,1/2,0) = -1/2*\log(1/2) - 1/2*\log(1/2) + 0 = 0.6931472$$

In a similar way, the other terms are 0.325083 and 1.098612.
So the final result is 1.084503 - (0.6931472 + 0.325083 + 1.098612)/3 = 0.378889

Comment: +1. Quick and dirty R calculation: `h <- function(x) {h <- function(x) {y <- x[x > 0]; -sum(y * log(y))}; jsd <- function(p,q) {h(q %*% p) - q %*% apply(p, 2, h)}`. Argument `p` is a matrix whose rows are the distributions and argument `q` is the vector of weights.  E.g., `p <- matrix(c(1/2,1/2,0, 0,1/10,9/10, 1/3,1/3,1/3), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE); q <- c(1/3,1/3,1/3); jsd(p,q)` returns $0.378889$ (which approximates the log of $3^{34/15} 5^{1/9} 2^{-13/45} 7^{-14/45} 37^{-37/90}$).

Comment: Not so dirty... ;-)

Comment: Thanks @whuber and @gui11aume! Just last questions: (1) The second term of the mixture shouldn't be 1/6+1/30+1/9 = 23/90 instead of 28/90 ? (2) The log must be the natural one ? and (3) The meaning of the result of of the JSD is supposed to be the average distance between all distributions ?

Comment: (1) Redo the math. (2) Entropy can be measured using any base of logarithm you like, as long as you are consistent. Natural, common, and base-2 logs are all conventional. (3) It's really a mean discrepancy between the distributions and their average. If you think of each distribution as a point, they form a cloud. You're looking at the average "distance" between the center of the cloud and its points, kind of like a mean radius. Intuitively, it measures the cloud's size.

Comment: @whuber: Just a quick clarification. Should it be `apply(p, 1, h)`? This is because, you mentioned `p` is a matrix whose *rows* are the distributions. I was trying this for the case of two distributions having 512 points and without changing 2 to 1, it was complaining about the matrices being non-conformable. Apologies in advance if I am wrong.

Comment: @Legend I think you're right. I did not test sufficiently after finding that one result agreed with the answer I obtained in another way (with *Mathematica*).

Comment: @whuber: +1 Thank you for confirming it :) Your implementation was of great help. Just for future reference, for your specific case, using 1 and 2 yielded the same answer.

Comment: Can someone provide the final version of the code with all the changes?

Comment: The code provided above is functional. The mistake was in the input.

Comment: whuber I think something is wrong with your example in 2 above. your vector q is 1x3, and your matrix p is 3x3.
so q %star% p works fine, but apply(p,2,h) returns a 1x3 matrix, so
q %star% apply(p,2,h) can't be computed. Happy to be shown what I'm missing. thanks dmck

Comment: @dmck There are indeed typos in my comment: (1) the phrase `h  <- function(x) {` was pasted twice. Just delete it: everything else works and produces the results I quote. Then modify the `apply(p, 2, h)` to `apply(p, 1, h)` as pointed out [in the comment by Legend](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29578/jensen-shannon-divergence-calculation-for-3-prob-distributions-is-this-ok/29581#comment93022_29581).

Answer (score 7):

Python:

```
import numpy as np
# @author: jonathanfriedman

def jsd(x,y): #Jensen-shannon divergence
    import warnings
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category = RuntimeWarning)
    x = np.array(x)
    y = np.array(y)
    d1 = x*np.log2(2*x/(x+y))
    d2 = y*np.log2(2*y/(x+y))
    d1[np.isnan(d1)] = 0
    d2[np.isnan(d2)] = 0
    d = 0.5*np.sum(d1+d2)    
    return d

jsd(np.array([0.5,0.5,0]),np.array([0,0.1,0.9]))
```

Java:

```
/**
 * Returns the Jensen-Shannon divergence.
 */
public static double jensenShannonDivergence(final double[] p1,
        final double[] p2) {
    assert (p1.length == p2.length);
    double[] average = new double[p1.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < p1.length; ++i) {
        average[i] += (p1[i] + p2[i]) / 2;
    }
    return (klDivergence(p1, average) + klDivergence(p2, average)) / 2;
}

public static final double log2 = Math.log(2);

/**
 * Returns the KL divergence, K(p1 || p2).
 * 
 * The log is w.r.t. base 2.
 * <p>
 * *Note*: If any value in <tt>p2</tt> is <tt>0.0</tt> then the
 * KL-divergence is <tt>infinite</tt>. Limin changes it to zero instead of
 * infinite.
 */
public static double klDivergence(final double[] p1, final double[] p2) {
    double klDiv = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < p1.length; ++i) {
        if (p1[i] == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        if (p2[i] == 0.0) {
            continue;
        } // Limin

        klDiv += p1[i] * Math.log(p1[i] / p2[i]);
    }
    return klDiv / log2; // moved this division out of the loop -DM
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A general version, for *n* probability distributions, in python based in Wikipedia formula and comments in this post with vector of weights (*pi*) as parameter and custom *logbase*:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import entropy as H


def JSD(prob_distributions, weights, logbase=2):
    # left term: entropy of mixture
    wprobs = weights * prob_distributions
    mixture = wprobs.sum(axis=0)
    entropy_of_mixture = H(mixture, base=logbase)

    # right term: sum of entropies
    entropies = np.array([H(P_i, base=logbase) for P_i in prob_distributions])
    wentropies = weights * entropies
    # wentropies = np.dot(weights, entropies)
    sum_of_entropies = wentropies.sum()

    divergence = entropy_of_mixture - sum_of_entropies
    return(divergence)

# From the original example with three distributions:
P_1 = np.array([1/2, 1/2, 0])
P_2 = np.array([0, 1/10, 9/10])
P_3 = np.array([1/3, 1/3, 1/3])

prob_distributions = np.array([P_1, P_2, P_3])
n = len(prob_distributions)
weights = np.empty(n)
weights.fill(1/n)

print(JSD(prob_distributions, weights))
```

> 0.546621319446

Answer (score 0):

You gave a Wikipedia reference. Here I give the complete expression for Jensen-Shannon divergence with multiple probability distributions:

$$JSmetric(p^1,...,p^m)=H(\frac{p^1+...+p^m}{m})-\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{m} H(p^j)}{m} $$

Original question was posted without mathematical expression of multi-distribution JS divergence which lead to a confusion in understanding the computation provided. Also, term `weight` was used which again causes confusion that how you select appropriate weights for multiplication. Above expression clarifies these confusions. As clear from above expression, weights are automatically chosen depending on the number of distribution.

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality, probably because it is so short.
At present it is more of a comment than an answer by our standards. Can you expand
on it? We can also turn it into a comment.

Comment: That sounds like a clarifying comment, rather than an answer. Should this be an edit into the question?

Comment: @ gung,  modified my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Scala version of JS divergence of two arbitrary length sequences:

```
def entropy(dist: WrappedArray[Double]) = -(dist.filter(_ != 0.0).map(i => i * Math.log(i)).sum)


val jsDivergence = (dist1: WrappedArray[Double], dist2: WrappedArray[Double]) => {
    val weights = 0.5 //since we are considering inly two sequences
    val left = dist1.zip(dist2).map(x => x._1 * weights + x._2 * weights)
    // println(left)
    // println(entropy(left))
    val right = (entropy(dist1) * weights) + (entropy(dist2) * weights)
    // println(right)
    entropy(left) - right

}

jsDivergence(Array(0.5,0.5,0), Array(0,0.1,0.9))

res0: Double = 0.557978817900054
```

Cross check this answer with code in the question edit section:

```
jsd([np.array([0.5,0.5,0]), np.array([0,0.1,0.9])])
0.55797881790005399
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any library so I created following Python code.
I cross verified with scipy implementation for 2 distributions and get the same result [source](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.jensenshannon.html).

```
# Calculates the JSD for multiple probability distributions
def jsd(self, prob_dists):
    weight = 1/len(prob_dists)              # Set weights to be uniform
    js_left = np.zeros(len(prob_dists[0]))  
    js_right = 0
        for pd in prob_dists:
            js_left += pd * weight
            js_right += weight * self.entropy(pd, normalize=False)

    jsd = self.entropy(js_left, normalize=False)-js_right
return jsd

# Entropy function
def entropy(self, prob_dist, normalize=True):
    entropy = -sum([p * math.log2(p) for p in prob_dist if p != 0])
    if normalize:
        max_entropy = math.log2(prob_dist.shape[0])
        return entropy/max_entropy
    return entropy
```