# Jensen-Shannon Divergence for multiple probability distributions?

Tags: distributions, python, entropy, information-theory, kullback-leibler

What is the correct mathematical expression for computing Jensen-Shannon divergence ($JSD$) between multiple probability distributions?

I found the following expression on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence), but I did not find any official reference:

$$JSD(p^1,...,p^m)=H\left(\frac{p^1+...+p^m}{m}\right)-\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{m} H(p^j)}{m}$$

where $H$ is the Shannon-entropy.

- What is the intuition of divergence in multiple distribution case?
- In the case of two *univariate* distributions $P$ & $Q$, it was interpreted as a distance between them $JSD(P||Q)$. So in the multi-distribution case, is it measuring the distance between two *multivariate* distributions?
- Is there an efficient Python code available for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found one paper that uses the JS-Divergence of multiple distributions to estimate the hardness of a query (in the area of Information Retrieval). The paper can be found [here](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/vip/study/publications_files/submitted_1.pdf) and they themselves refer a paper called "Divergence measures based on the shannon entropy (1991)". They also give a little bit different mathematical expression for it.

As for the interpretation, they explain it as follows:

> Given a set of distributions thus obtained, we employ the well known Jensen-Shannon divergence [8] to measure the diversity of the distributions corresponding [...]
>   So the Jensen-Shannon divergence can be seen to measure the overall diversity between all the probability distributions.

As for the Python code, I couldn't find any package that implements the JSD for more than two distributions. But there is already one quite straightforward code example on crossvalidated (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29578/jensen-shannon-divergence-calculation-for-3-prob-distributions-is-this-ok))

.

Comment: @ Bobipuegi Python code you referred is for `2` distributions only while I was looking for a general case. Anyway, I can write it myself as I have done for `2` distributions. Also, the paper you referred does not give exactly the same expression as given in my question, so I am not sure if it is correct (though I have seen on Stack Exchange someone using above expression). I want to make sure which expression is the correct one. More importantly, my question is about understanding intuition behind multi-distribution JS divergence. Between which distributions does it compute distance?

Comment: 1. I cannot do the math right now, but it seems to me that the formula you give and the one in the paper are equivalent after a bit of reshaping.  2. the Python code in the link I attached is able to handle multiple distributions 3. as cited in the paper, the js-divergence of multiple distributions isn't a distance measure but an overall diversity measure

Comment: @ Bobipuegi So is it `JS(P1 vs. P2, P3,...,Pn)` or `JS(P1 vs. P2 vs. P3 vs....vs., Pn)` or something like this?

Comment: @ Bobipuegi  For `2` distributions, it is `JS(P vs. Q)`

Comment: I understand it as first calculating a "centroid" distribution and then calculating something like JS(P1vs. Centroid, P2 vs. Centroid .... Pn vs. Centroid)

Comment: Regarding the equivalence of the two formulations:
The paper I linked to contains a reference to some older paper, which uses the same expression you cited from wikipedia. So you can refer that one as source. You can find it here: [link](http://sansan.phy.ncu.edu.tw/~hclee/ref/Lin_divergenceIEEE91.pdf)  (You find your formula on page 5, formula 5.1)

Comment: And how to compute centroid distribution? I know the old paper. I read it a long time ago. Thanks!

Comment: You can just use the formula you found on Wikipedia, no need to explicitly follow the calculations using the centroids. I just think it's more intuitive to think about divergence from an average as it's done in the paper I first linked

Comment: Ah, but if you knew the old paper I linked, why did you write you didn't knew any official reference for the Wikipedia formula? Isn't that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia has the formula on this, and the references about Information Radius (I think it is the first 2) should give you the formula.
Another reference is work by Bob Williamson at ANU (Australian National University).  You should be able to find him on Scholar.google.com.  Good luck and thanks for asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any library so I created following Python code.
I cross verified with scipy implementation for 2 distributions and get the same result [source](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.jensenshannon.html).

```
# Calculates the JSD for multiple probability distributions
def jsd(self, prob_dists):
    weight = 1/len(prob_dists)              # Set weights to be uniform
    js_left = np.zeros(len(prob_dists[0]))  
    js_right = 0
    for pd in prob_dists:
        js_left += pd * weight
        js_right += weight * self.entropy(pd, normalize=False)

    jsd = self.entropy(js_left, normalize=False)-js_right
    return jsd

# Entropy function
def entropy(self, prob_dist, normalize=True):
    entropy = -sum([p * math.log2(p) for p in prob_dist if p != 0])
    if normalize:
        max_entropy = math.log2(prob_dist.shape[0])
        return entropy/max_entropy
    return entropy
```